# Setting up a Bulletin Board

Tags: social-networking

I want to add a "Community" section (Bulletin Board) to my website so everyone can communicate, but I don't know what I'm doing.

How would I go about adding this and which one offers the most documentation and support?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, make certain that you read the instructions on configuring your discussion software to protect you and your community for the worst parts of the internet: spam, spoofing, and abuse.

Make certain that you immediately change the admin password from the one that comes with the installation.

If you leave your communities wide open to all kinds of posting, harvesting, and general mis-use, you'll spend your days playing whack-a-mole with thousands of idiots.  Develop your acceptable use policy, configure your boards to support it, then enforce it.

And if the software you are looking at doesn't support things like e-mail verification, moderation, abuse reporting, anti-spamming controls, etc., just keep looking.

Be prepared to spend time managing your community so that it doesn't become another one of the millions of web forums out there full of off topic posts that drive people away from your website.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you needed is a forum software, there are tones of free and open source ones available on the net. DotNetNuke is a .NET one but can be expensive to host and phpBB is another popular choice and there are a lot of cheap hosting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.phpbb.com/) is what you need.
Edit: They don't offer a hosted version there. You can use [this](http://pro-forums.com/) instead. It's hosted on it's own site, free, and doesn't require a download.

Comment: If you're using PHP, sure. If not, no.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought that site had the service of HOSTED phpBB forums. There are other sites for that: http://www.pro-forums.com/

That way you don't have to download anything and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

is your site based on php/mysql or asp/sql? Chances are if you do not know where to even find tables, that you are not able to what you actually want.

HOWEVER, if it's php/mysql, i recommend [Cool Php Scripts](http://www.amazon.ca/Wicked-Cool-PHP-Real-World-Difficult/dp/1593271735) book. It covers creating sort of a community forum/message board.

As i said again, you are probably not going to do it alone, at least, without a long frustrating learning curve.

You can always post a job and someone would be more than willing to bid on it at elance or rentacoder or any other site of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has [a big honking list of forum software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software). Pick the one that best matches the programming language(s) you're familiar with, the features you need, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I find [Vanilla](http://getvanilla.com/) to be a much better forum application that phpBB for reasons of aesthetics as well as extensibility.  I have not seen/used it in a situation where many sub-forums were required, so depending on your scope it may not be the right choice, but for small-to-medium sized forums I'd suggest trying it first.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to choose a forum software that matchs your requirements.

Then, just follow the Installation Guide provided by the software you have choosen.

More information at [Forum Software Reviews](http://www.forum-software.org)